# Диагональное преобладание матрицы

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо написать метод Якоби для решения СЛАУ на C++. Возникла проблема с диагональным преобладание матрицы. Чтобы метод сошелся необходимо чтобы диагональный элемент по модулю был больше или равен чем сумма модулей всех остальных элементов строки. Если это не выполняется изначально необходимо преобразовать матрицу. У меня была идея обнулить верхнюю и нижнюю часть матрицы, оставить только диагональные элементы, но при обычной матрице(3;3):

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

после обнуления нижнего треугольника, нижняя строка обнуляется полностью и я не могу тем самым обнулить верхний треугольник. Подскажите наиболее простое решение задачи буду благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @LaKO: Это вопрос на [маткод](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: @VladD там никто даже комментария не оставил)

Comment: а зачем вам преобладание? это же достаточное условие сходимости, но не необходимое.  по-моему, проще проверить сходимость итерационно, чем преобразовывать матрицу непонятно каким образом, а учитывая достаточность - не обязательно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, итерационно мы можем сказать, что метод сходится(если это так). 
А если он не сходится или сходится, но не равномерно? Итерационно этот процесс слишком дорог. 

@LaKO,Если Вы простыми преобразованиями занулили строку, то это означает, что система линейно зависима, т.е. решение существует, НО НЕ ЕДИНСТВЕННО.

Если говорить о том, чтобы программно занулять матрицу, то почему бы не воспользоваться методом Гаусса? В данном случае он будет лучше, при условии, что все равно будем занулять. 

Я не понял, что Вы собираетесь занулять - что такой "верхняя часть".

Comment: @andrw, если вы почитаете о предназначении метода Якоби, вы узнаете, что он применяется, когда метод Гаусса становится менее эффективным - большое количество переменных => количество вычислений, время выполнения. Метод Гаусса слишком дорог. При выполнении достаточного условия, описанного ТС, метод сходится как геометрическая прогрессия, т.е. достаточно быстро.    
Если метод не сходится равномерно, тогда он не вообще не сходится, иначе формула для достижения определенной точности была бы не верна. Откуда это предположение взято вообще непонятно.   
И еще раз "достаточное" != "необходимое".

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, если говорить, про эффективность, то уместно ли тут говорить про проверку на сходимость итерационно? 
Да, пожалуй, метод Якоби эффективней, но если вопрос стоит, как - решить систему или не решить её вовсе, то уж лучше решить. 

Допустим, проверили мы на сходимость систему - она медленно сходилась, а потом разошлась. Мы затратили кучу ресурсов, так и не решив её. Такой подход имеет место быть..но такое расточительство далеко не всегда уместно.

Comment: @andrw, ну так найдите простое необходимое условие, проверьте его в пару арифметических действий и вопрос будет решен. Я видел только необходимое и достаточное условие, для которого придется решить слау не менее сложную, чем исходная. Тем временем диагональное преобладание дает только положительный ответ на вопрос "сходится ли метод?"  
Медленно сходилась, а потом разошлась - это вы не про слау, там либо расходится либо сходится.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, хм..точно. мы же про СЛАУ говорим.
Вы абсолютно правы, в своих рассуждениях я упускал то, что мы говорим про линейные уравнения.